# Advertencias y Errores en la instalación de Paquetes al crear un primer nuevo proyecto en Angular (recién instalado)

Tags: nodejs, angular, angular-cli

Hola gusto en saludarles, disculpen, soy estudiante y recien estoy instalando Angular-Cli y Node.js pero me tope con Advertencias y Errores al crear mi primer proyecto siguiendo las indicaciones de este video para Windows 10 (Previo a este video seguí los 2 anteriores, donde instalé Node.js y Angular-Cli, en este último le cambien las ejecuciones de "Policies" con Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted para poder trabajar normalmente):

https://youtu.be/ed06mt4YuEk

Les agradecería si me ayudaran a saber qué es o qué puedo hacer para solucionarlo y así poder empezar a trabajar y aprender Angular, por lo que entiendo se debe a versiones obsoletas de algunas cosas y las dependencias, pero ya actualicé con "ng update" y todo está al día y sigue igual, de antemano agradezco su tiempo y apoyo *;)*

### Click en en link de la imagén:

[Imagen de Advertencias y Errores en la instalación de paquetes (automática al crear un nuevo proyecto con Angular)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmTli.png)

### Texto de la imagen:

```
PS C:\Users\Luis\angularProjects> ng new portfolio-app
? Would you like to add Angular routing? Yes
? Which stylesheet format would you like to use? CSS
CREATE portfolio-app/angular.json (3081 bytes)
CREATE portfolio-app/package.json (1075 bytes)
CREATE portfolio-app/README.md (1058 bytes)
CREATE portfolio-app/tsconfig.json (783 bytes)
CREATE portfolio-app/.editorconfig (274 bytes)
CREATE portfolio-app/.gitignore (604 bytes)
CREATE portfolio-app/.browserslistrc (703 bytes)
CREATE portfolio-app/karma.conf.js (1430 bytes)
CREATE portfolio-app/tsconfig.app.json (287 bytes)
CREATE portfolio-app/tsconfig.spec.json (333 bytes)
CREATE portfolio-app/src/favicon.ico (948 bytes)
CREATE portfolio-app/src/index.html (298 bytes)
CREATE portfolio-app/src/main.ts (372 bytes)
CREATE portfolio-app/src/polyfills.ts (2820 bytes)
CREATE portfolio-app/src/styles.css (80 bytes)
CREATE portfolio-app/src/test.ts (788 bytes)
CREATE portfolio-app/src/assets/.gitkeep (0 bytes)
CREATE portfolio-app/src/environments/environment.prod.ts (51 bytes)
CREATE portfolio-app/src/environments/environment.ts (658 bytes)
CREATE portfolio-app/src/app/app-routing.module.ts (245 bytes)
CREATE portfolio-app/src/app/app.module.ts (393 bytes)
CREATE portfolio-app/src/app/app.component.html (24617 bytes)
CREATE portfolio-app/src/app/app.component.spec.ts (1094 bytes)
CREATE portfolio-app/src/app/app.component.ts (217 bytes)
CREATE portfolio-app/src/app/app.component.css (0 bytes)
\ Installing packages (npm)...npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated flatten@1.0.3: flatten is deprecated in favor of utility frameworks such as lodash.
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm ERR! cb() never called!

npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://npm.community>

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Luis\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-09-20T18_28_25_142Z-debug.log
× Package install failed, see above.
The Schematic workflow failed. See above.
```

### Versiones de herramientas:

```
Angular CLI: 12.2.6
Node: 14.17.6
Package Manager: npm 6.14.15
OS: win32 x64

Angular: <error>
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router
```

### Package                         Version

```
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1202.6 (cli-only)        
@angular-devkit/build-angular   <error>
@angular-devkit/core            12.2.6 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/schematics      12.2.6 (cli-only)
@angular/cli                    12.2.6 (cli-only)
@schematics/angular             12.2.6 (cli-only)
rxjs                            6.6.7 (cli-only)
typescript                      <error>
```